# Understanding Random monad in Scala

Tags: scala, random, monads

This a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647407/monte-carlo-calculation-of-pi-in-scala)

[Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) pointed out that `java.util.Random` is side-effecting and suggested a random monad `Rng` [library](https://github.com/NICTA/rng) to make the code purely functional. Now I am trying to build a simplified random monad by myself to understand how it works.

Does it make sense ? How would you fix/improve the explanation below ?

### Random Generator

First we plagiarize a random generating function from `java.util.Random`

```
 // do some bit magic to generate a new random "seed" from the given "seed" 
 // and return both the new "seed" and a random value based on it

 def next(seed: Long, bits: Int): (Long, Int) = ...
```

Note that `next` returns *both* the new seed and the value rather than just the value. We need it to pass the new seed to another function invocation.

### Random Point

Now let's write a function to generate a random point in a unit square.

Suppose we have a function to generate a random double in range [0, 1]

```
 def randomDouble(seed: Long): (Long, Double) = ... // some bit magic
```

Now we can write a function to generate a random point.

```
def randomPoint(seed: Long): (Long, (Double, Double)) = {
   val (seed1, x) = randomDouble(seed)
   val (seed2, y) = randomDouble(seed1)
   (seed2, (x, y)) 
}
```

So far, so good and both `randomDouble` and `randomPoint` are pure. The only problem is that we compose `randomDouble` to build `randomPoint` *ad hoc*. We don't have a *generic* tool to compose functions yielding random values.

### Monad *Random*

Now we will define a *generic* tool to compose functions yielding random values. First, we generalize the type of `randomDouble`:

```
type Random[A] = Long => (Long, A) // generate a random value of type A
```

and then build a wrapper class around it.

```
class Random[A](run: Long => (Long, A))
```

We need the wrapper to define methods `flatMap` (as *bind* in Haskell) and `map` used by *for-comprehension*.

```
class Random[A](run: Long => (Long, A)) {
  def apply(seed: Long) = run(seed)  

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Random[B]): Random[B] =
    new Random({seed: Long => val (seed1, a) = run(seed); f(a)(seed1)})

  def map[B](f: A => B): Random[B] =
    new Random({seed: Long = val (seed1, a) = run(seed); (seed1, f(a))})
}
```

Now we add a *factory*-function to create a trivial `Random[A]` (which is absolutely deterministic rather than "random", by the way) This is a *return* function (as *return* in Haskell).

```
def certain[A](a: A) = new Random({seed: Long => (seed, a)})
```

`Random[A]` is a *computation* yielding random value of type A. The methods `flatMap` , `map`, and function `unit` serves for *composing* simple computations to build more complex ones. For example, we will compose two `Random[Double]` to build `Random[(Double, Double)]`.

### Monadic Random Point

Now when we have a monad we are ready to revisit `randomPoint` and `randomDouble`. Now we define them differently as functions yielding `Random[Double]` and `Random[(Double, Double)]`

```
def randomDouble(): Random[Double] = new Random({seed: Long => ... })
def randomPoint(): Random[(Double, Double)] =
  randomDouble().flatMap(x => randomDouble().flatMap(y => certain(x, y))
```

This implementation is *better* than the previous one since it uses a *generic* tool (`flatMap` and `certain`) to compose two calls of `Random[Double]` and build `Random[(Double, Double)]`.

Now can re-use this tool to build more functions generating random values.

### Monte-Carlo calculation of Pi

Now we can use `map` to test if a random point is in the circle:

```
def randomCircleTest(): Random[Boolean] = 
  randomPoint().map {case (x, y) => x * x + y * y <= 1}
```

We can also define a Monte-Carlo simulation in terms of `Random[A]`

```
def monteCarlo(test: Random[Boolean], trials: Int): Random[Double] = ...
```

and finally the function to calculate PI

```
def pi(trials: Int): Random[Double] = ....
```

All those functions are pure. Side-effects occur only when we finally apply the `pi` function to get the value of pi.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. I'd suggest writing `val randomDouble = ...` instead of `def randomDouble() = ...`, though, to emphasize that these are pure values—just computations with no side effects.

Comment: Thank you. If I follow this logic I should write `val randomPoint = ...` instead of `def randomPoint()`, etc. since all functions are pure. Is it correct ?

Comment: Two points: using `()` on the `def` suggests that the method has side effects (just convention, but it makes sense to follow it). More importantly, using `def` instead of `val` means calling `randomDouble` twice in `randomPoint` constructs two `Random` instances, while you only need one.

Comment: Thanks. You are right: `randomPoint` constructs two instances of `Random[Double]`. Good point ! :) I should fix it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the point here.  You can pass in a RNG to use and have it internally update state and avoid the **twenty-fold** performance penalty that this method gave in benchmarking on your other question.  Aside from inner satisfaction that it is possible to make explicit every state change as an explicit parameter pass (which is a nice exercise to do to convince yourself that you can), what is the problem here that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RexKerr The point is to learn about RNG rather than just calculate Pi with Monte-Carlo. Does it make sense ? Do you think the RNG approach ("random" monad) is useful ?

Comment: @RexKerr Your comment made me wonder _when_ PRG (or another approach based on a random monad) is useful and practical. It is probably not practical to calculate Pi. So what is the _minimal_ example, where is PRG is useful _more_ than the obvious straightforward side-effecting approach ? I will probably ask it as a separate question on SO.

Comment: @Michael - As someone who has used RNGs extensively for decades, I can think of precisely zero cases where anything would have been aided by having a monad aside from some extra bookkeeping that I don't want to do explicitly (and that's assuming it were no slower!).  I grant that there could be _some_ cases where the exact weaving of the random number stream through the code becomes exquisitely important, but in practice I've never found one (including in a stochastic reaction-diffusion simulator where reproducibility given a certain seed or set thereof was essential).

Comment: @RexKerr Thank your comments. I will think about it.

Comment: @Michael - While thinking, note that I tend to do a lot of computation-heavy usage of RNGs.  That may color my perspective a bit.

Comment: @RexKerr the monad structure makes it very easy to test (it's kind of enforced "dependency injection") and enforces that the exact weaving is deterministic, meaning reproducibility based on a particular seed is enforced by the compiler. It also makes it very clear which of your higher-level methods use random input and which are deterministic, because whether a particular method uses randomness is right there in the method type.

Comment: @lmm - Why would I want it in the method type instead of the method signature, or the identity of the class?  (Also, dependency injection is good at hiding what things depend on, not making all your types reflect what things depend on.)

Comment: @RexKerr why as a type rather than the method or class name? The same reasons for using type safety anywhere. Why a monadic return type rather than a method parameter? `for`/`yield` composition, and all the libraries that operate on generic `Monad`s. ((DI is fundamentally about saying a class' dependencies should be injected into that class from outside, not constructed or located by the class itself))

Comment: @lmm - This isn't the place for an extended discussion, so I will just state that I haven't found any of those things needed or helpful in this particular context.  I think code examples would be needed to have any hope of making progress.

Comment: @RexKerr Interestingly one of the examples in the Functional Programming in Scala book is monadic random generators (chapter 6). One of the use cases were to generate (reproducible) test cases, though probably without them those could also be easily implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is quite nice although it is a little bit complicated. I also suggested you to take a look at Chapter 6 of [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) By *Paul Chiusano* and *Runar Bjarnason*. 
The chapter is called *Purely Functional State* and it shows how to create purely functional random generator and define its data type algebra on top of that to have full function composition support.