# Random integer in [0, N] in Scala

Tags: scala, random, monads

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704000/understanding-random-monad-in-scala)

Suppose I have a `RandomGen[A]` monad. 
This is actually a function: `Long => (Long, A)` with `map` and `flatMap` and another function `certain` to create a new instance of `RandomGen` (as *return* in Haskell)

```
class RandomGen[A](run: Long => (Long, A)) {

  def apply(seed: Long) = run(seed)

  def flatMap[B](f: A => RandomGen[B]): RandomGen[B] =
    new RandomGen(seed => {val (seed1, a) = run(seed); f(a)(seed1)})

  def map[B](f: A => B): RandomGen[B] =
    new RandomGen(seed => {val (seed1, a) = run(seed); (seed1, f(a))})
}

def certain[A](a: A): RandomGen[A] = new RandomGen(seed => (seed, a))
```

Suppose also I have a *generator* of random `bits`

```
def nextbits(bits: Int): RandomGen[Int] = ...
```

Now I would like to add new *generator* that yields random numbers between 0 and a given `n`.  I copied the implementation from [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and omitted the special case where `n` is a power of two for simplicity.

```
def integer(n: Int): RandomGen[Int] = 
  nextbits(31).flatMap {r =>
    val value = r % n
    if (r - value + (n -1) < 0) integer(n) else certain(value)
  }
```

Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Note that this is just the State monad, so you could reuse the scalaz implementation of that if you like. Also you could use map instead of flatMap and avoid needing to call certain.

Comment: I did not figure out how to use `map` i/o `flatMap`. Could you show a code to do that ?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I missed the recursion, no, the `flatMap` approach is good.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the `integer` above with _for-comprehension_ ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but since you only have one `flatMap` I don't think it would be worth it. `for` comprehensions are great for expressing a long chain of `flatMap` calls and avoiding the "pyramid of doom" effect.