# How to "sum" stream of monoid values in Scala?

Tags: scala, random, scalaz, fold, monoids

Suppose I am using the [Rng](https://github.com/NICTA/rng) library for simple Monte Carlo simulation (as in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647407/monte-carlo-calculation-of-pi-in-scala)).

```
val d      : Rng[Double] = double
val point  : Rng[(Double, Double)] = pair(d, d)
val points = point.stream(1000)
val tests  = points.map(point => if (insideCircle(point)) 1.0 else 0.0)
```

Now I need to *sum* all items of `tests`

```
tests[0] |+| tests[1] |+| tests[2] ... // Rng[Double] is a monoid
```

I can do it with `fold` but I would like to use some "shortcut" (smth. like `sum: Seq[M[A]] => M[A]`, where M is a monoid), instead. Do `scala` or `scalaz` have such a function ?

Comment: In haskell it's called `mconcat` if that helps.

Comment: You could use `foldMap(point => ...)` instead of `map` to get sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scalaz has various [ops](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.syntax.FoldableOps) e.g. `suml`, assuming there's a `Foldable` typeclass instance for `Stream`.